# Does STUN protocol forward packets inside the NAT?

Tags: ip, wireshark, nat, packets, stun

I'm using an application located on the web that use stun. In WireShark I've noticed that my computer is trying to reach some private IP's inside my NAT using this protocol.
My computer private IP is: 192.168.2.175

Why does it work this way? Is there a way to stop it ?

Here is the WireShark capture:
[image: here is the WireShark capture]